# prevent updatepanel to update on specific event

Tags: asp.net

here is my code when I select value from dropdownlist dl_past update panel has been update

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" class="card" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
     <ContentTemplate>

         <div class="card-header">
             <div class="row align-items-center">
                 <div class="col-md">
                     Game Type 
                     <asp:DropDownList>
                         <!-- some items -->
                     </asp:DropDownList>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md">
                     Past Days
                     <asp:DropDownList ID="dl_past" title="choose past" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dl_past_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                         <asp:ListItem Text="Today" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem Text="Yesterday" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem Text="Last 7 days" Value="7" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem Text="Last 10 days" Value="10"></asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem Text="Last 30 days" Value="30"></asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem Text="Custom Date" Value="custom"></asp:ListItem>
                     </asp:DropDownList>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col" id="div_dates1" runat="server">
                     From Date
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txt_fromdate" title="From Date" runat="server" TextMode="Date" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col" id="div_dates2" runat="server">
                     To Date
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txt_todate" title="To date" runat="server" TextMode="Date" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md text-center">
                     
                     <asp:LinkButton ID="btn_search" runat="server" OnClick="btn_search_Click" CssClass="btn btn-info">Search</asp:LinkButton>
                     <a class="btn btn-info" href="">Reset</a>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>

     </ContentTemplate>
     <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_search" EventName="Click" />
     </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I want that it should update only by the btn_search click.
In the update panel 2 events are there one for dropdown, another for button.

Comment: then remove the auto post back for the drop down, remove the post back trigger (you don't need that). Then remove your down down code stub, and move that dropdown code to the button click code.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal i needed dl_past_SelectedIndexChanged for some validation thats why I used postback="auto"

Comment: Ok, but if you want to "hold off" or not do that validation until the button is clicked, then you most likely want to remove the auto post back, and place all that code behind the button click - not have both, and thus the button click 100% does the work and checking - not both combo and button click.  However, if some combo verification still has to occur, then the auto post back for combo is fine. Just that the final code you want to check everything should now go in the button code stub.